# Does Artifactory support partial file upload?

Tags: upload, artifactory

I'm working a **Python 3** script to download data from a server in chunk of data (~1MB each, but can be setup externally).

Each block downloaded  must be uploaded to a JFrog Artifactory (JA) server (*version 5.4.6,  revision 50406900*).

I'm using the HTTP Header '**Content-Range**' to send the data blocks.  But the JA is replacing the old data and keeping only the last block.
The test file has 1164 byte and the header was sent right, with test block of 512 bytes (test only, no need big file to test it)!

```
- BLK#1: bytes 0-511/1164
- BLK#2: bytes 512-1023/1164
- BLK#3: bytes 1024-1163/1164
```

**NOTE: Each PUT on JA was answered with a HTTP RC 201 (Created).**

The syntax look all right (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Range).

The first two blocks was 512 bytes long and the last one with 140 bytes. So we got the 1164 bytes of file.

I'm digging through the official documentation, but haven't been able to find a answer.

1. Does JFrog Artifactory able to receive partial uploads?
2. If so, how I can acomplish it?

Comment: AFAIK, Artifactory does not support these partial uploads. The REST API (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API) does not show it. Did you get an indication that it does?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to solve the JFrog Artifactory *annoying failure on partial upload of big files*.

I just created a inherited class of the `io.RawIOBase`, a base class of Python 3. After a few tests I got the list of basic methods which I must implement.

```
class MemoryFile(io.RawIOBase):
```

**Just get the test with a basic usage sample code:**

```
# Each side must have a session to avoid issues
downReq = requests.Session()
# Here the request with all security tokens and required params (I'm ignoring SSL check for test)
response = downReq.get(urlTargetFile,stream=True, verify=False)
# My custom class take a Response as constructor argument
fpIn = MemoryFile(response)

# Another session to upload the date
upReq = requests.Session()
# Call the JFrog Artifactory address 
upResp = upReq.put(urlUp, data=fpIn , headers=headers, verify=False, stream=True)
# The SHA-256 hash to save into Audit Log
print("SHA-256: ", fp.hash())
```

Comment: It'd be great if you could share the implementation, in case you have open-sourced it already. I'm working on a similar problem with the Nexus artifact store. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post placeholder/stub answers. Wait until you can post the actual content you want to share, and then post the answer. Also, as a general note, please don't abuse formatting so much. Things like bold and italics should be used for emphasis where called for, not for stylizing your post.